# Cloudant endpoint DNS cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, ibm-cloud, cloudant

We have for some time been using **Cloudant** NoSQL from the IBM Cloud and we have been extremely happy with the speed, simplicity and reliability.  BUT a few weeks ago our front-end server which stores data in Cloudant database startet periodically to log exceptions: `"The remote name could not be resolved: '[A unique ID]-bluemix.cloudant.com" at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream`.

I added a DNS lookup when the error occurs which logs: `"This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server" at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)`.

This relaxed error message indicates it is not harmful but for us it is.

We see the error for 1-3 minutes every 30-120 minutes on servers but not while debugging locally (this could be lack of patience and/or traffic).

Below is one method of seven which fails

```cs
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Configuration.Cloudant.ApiKey, Configuration.Cloudant.ApiPassword);
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var uri = new Uri(Configuration.Cloudant.Url); //{https://[A unique ID]-bluemix.cloudant.com/[Our Product]/_find}
        var stringContent = new StringContent(QueryFromResource(),
                                UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json");
        var task = TaskEx.Run(async () => await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent));
        task.Wait(); // <------ Exception here
        if (task.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
           // Handle response deleted
        }
    }
}
```

We have updated our .Net framework, experimented with DnsRefreshTimeout, refactored code, extended caching but we keep seeing the issue.

We also added a DNS lookup to Google when the error occurs and this is consistently successful.

Initially we thought load might we an issue but we see the issue even when there is no traffic.

Suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Hej Per -- please email support@cloudant.com with the above, but including your XYZ-bluemix account name so we can investigate properly. Kind regards - stefan@cloudant

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thank you for the pointer. I’m in dialog with support. /Per